# Python Apply Function to All Elements of Array Less Than 0

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I want to apply a function to all the elements of my matrix which are less than or equal to 0 which takes as an argument that element.

```
   my_matrix[my_matrix <= 0] = 3 * (func(my_input_here))
```

So for example, if we have

```
[0 3 5
-3 5 3
 9 2 -1]
```

I want to replace `-3` with `3 * func(-3)` and `-1` with `3 * func(-1)`

Comment: If func  accepts vectorized operations , `np.where(my_matrix <= 0, 3*func(my_matrix), my_matrix)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am creating a dummy function which just adds by 1. And also simulating the matrix in variable `m`.

```
m = [[0, 3, 5],
    [-3, 5, 3],
     [9, 2, -1]]

def my_func(x):
    return x + 1

m = [[element if element > 0 else 3 * my_func(element) for element in row ] for row in m] 
print(m)
```

Output:

```
[[3, 3, 5],
 [-6, 5, 3], 
[9, 2, 0]]
```